# How to setParallelism for flink Table other than Stream

Tags: apache-flink

Just as the title, i used a lot of setParallelism when i am only use DataStream API in my stream app.

Recently i found table API is better to use in my scenario, as it can unify batch/stream apps which usually have to be 2 different, save a lot of duplicate code only using different dataset/datastream apis. but when i tried to port my stream app to table API. i found there are no setParallelism supported for Table.

I have to do this by my customized APIs like this.

can anyone help me with:

1, there are no need to set parallelism for table, why?

2, if still necessary to setParallelism for Table, how to achieve this in another way better than my tedious one ?

```
static public DataStream<Row> getRowStreamParallelismed(DataStream<Row> input, Integer parallelism) {
    return ((DataStreamSource<Row>) input)
            .setParallelism(parallelism)
            .map((MapFunction<Row, Row>) value -> {
                return value;
            })
            //.startNewChain()
            ;
}

static public Table getTableParallelismed(Table input, Integer parallelism, StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv) {
    RowTypeInfo rowTypeInfo = MyType.getRowTypeInfo(input);
    DataStream<Row> rowInput = tableEnv.toAppendStream(input, rowTypeInfo);
    DataStream<Row> parallelismed = MyStream.getRowStreamParallelismed(rowInput, parallelism);
    Table ret = tableEnv.fromDataStream(parallelismed, String.join(",", rowTypeInfo.getFieldNames()));
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [table.exec.resource.default-parallelism](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/table/config.html#table-exec-resource-default-parallelism) in order to set the parallelism value.

If you set this config parameter it will override  the StreamContext parallelism value.

```
// instantiate table environment
TableEnvironment tEnv = ...

tEnv.getConfig()        // access high-level configuration
  .getConfiguration()   // set low-level key-value options
  .setString("table.exec.resource.default-parallelism", ***parallelism***)
```